# How to update mysql data when using explode

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code to load the month of the birthday that corresponds to the id number:

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT BIRTHDAY FROM student WHERE IDNO='".$_GET['id']."'";
    if($result = mysql_query($query))  
    {
        if($success = mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
        {
?>
<select title="- Select Month -" name="mm" id="mm" class="" > 
<?php

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
           list($year,$month,$day)=explode("-", $row['BIRTHDAY']);
?> 
             <option value="<?php echo $month;?>"><?php echo $month; ?></option>\n";
```

And this is the form action:

```
$birthday = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mm']); 

mysql_query("UPDATE student SET YEAR = FIRSTNAME='$fname',  BIRTHDAY='$birthday'
WHERE IDNO ='$idnum'");
```

What should I do, when I click on the update button, it executes, but I see the  undefined offset error is stored in  the mysql database and not the month.
I'm just a beginner, can you give me some tips on how can I achieve updating the data

Comment: what is the data type of BIRTHDAY in your database, if it is of date type then value can't get inserted

Comment: AAAHHHH SQL INJECTION AUGHHHHHHH

Comment: Your query that uses $_GET is not safe. Someone could type in mypage.php?idno='OR 1=1;UPDATE student SET firstname='Trolololo';--

Comment: yeah thanks, I'll fix this first.

Comment: will this solve the problem of sql injection?: $idnum = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT BIRTHDAY FROM student WHERE IDNO='$idnum'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this... you will have to use 3 selects and then join them to update the database... so, in the form you have something like this:

```
<select name='month'>
    <option value='1'>January</option>
    <option value='xx'>etc</option>
</select>
<select name='day'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='xx'>etc</option>
</select>
<select name='year'>
    <option value='1980'>1980</option>
    <option value='xx'>etc</option>
</select>
```

Then... the PHP that receives that data should do something like:

```
$year = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['year']);
$month = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['month']);
$day = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['day']);

$birthday = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
mysql_query("UPDATE student SET YEAR = FIRSTNAME='$fname',  BIRTHDAY='$birthday'
WHERE IDNO ='$idnum'");
```

Of course... you have to verify first whether all variables are set or not. You can do so by using the [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) method.

Answer (score -1):

Check your update query, It may be wrong in that.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE student SET YEAR = FIRSTNAME='$fname',  BIRTHDAY='$birthday'
WHERE IDNO ='$idnum'");
```

See this year and firstname, in this year is assigned to null character for you.

Just assign like this,

```
$birthday = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mm']);
```

Comment: NO! BAD! `mysql_real_escape_string` is a must! SQL injection! Don't ignore best practices!

Comment: hi mattbasta, shall i know what type of sql injection it will got?

Comment: Any time you put raw data from the user (i.e.: `$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc.) directly into a MySQL query without running it through `mysql_real_escape_string`, there's a chance that a hacker can hack your database and cause large amounts of damage. Always always always use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Oh really. Ok thanks mattbasta.  I didnt use that if some times i use mysql_real_escape_string i will get error.  why it is?  would you know that.